# Is Samantha already a famous singer?

Tags: plot-explanation, just-friends

In *Just Friends* is Samantha James already an established pop singer, or is she more of a socialite, Paris Hilton type, who's working on her first album?

Chris' boss wants her to sign on with his label. If she were already a famous singer I'd think she'd already be signed with a label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no indication that Samantha is an established or signed artist.

The news report states...

[image]

> First up tonight, you've seen her in the pages of magazines, and well, the opening of practically anything, but what what you may not know about this "it" girl...is her humanitarian side.

If she were already a *famous singer* it would have been mentioned and Samantha would not have needed to announce her album by latching onto supposed 'humanitarian' works.

Plus...she's a **terrible** singer. :)

Comment: That's what I assumed. Somehow along the way I got a little confused though. Thanks very much for your answer. :)